# Dealing with 0 values when calculating the mle for a Dirichlet distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, dirichlet-distribution

I have $N$ pmfs, and for each each $L$ samples. Each sample has a variable amount of $x$ values, but the $x$ values that they have can be matched. So for example:

$$sample_1 \rightarrow\ x_1 = 0, x_2 = 0, x_3 = 0.2, x_4 = 0.4, x_5 = 0.4$$
$$sample_2 \rightarrow\ x_1 = 0.3,x_2=0, x_3 = 0.4, x_4 = 0.3,x_5=0$$

I'm using a [python program](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dirichlet/0.7) to calculate the mle from the samples which is a port of Thomas P. Minka's Matlab Fastfit code ([Estimating a Dirichlet Distribution](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/papers/dirichlet/)).

The problem is that, for fitting, it sums over $logp+psi(\sum^k a_k) - logp$. Since some of the $x$ values are 0, some logp values are -inf. Therefore, summing over this makes everything -inf.

How can I deal with 0 values when calculating the mle for a Dirichlet distribution?

Comment: If $x_i = 0$, then $\log(p_i^{x_i}) = 0$.  I'd deal with it by dropping the corresponding $i$s from your model, setting the corresponding $\hat{p_i} = 0$ (the MLE), and fitting on the rest of the data.  (Then of course adding back in the elements you removed for fitting purposes.)

Comment: @jbowman I'm not sure if I understand what you mean precisely, could you elaborate? Do you mean, in this example, dropping $x_1$ for both $sample_1$ and $sample_2$, or only for $sample_1$? In the former case, I have many samples and for almost all $i$ at least one $p_i^{x_i}$ is 0, so then I don't have many left over. If it's the latter case I don't see how that would be done, but I'll know where to look.

Comment: Hmmm, I may have misunderstood the problem.  Are you assuming the $i^{th}$ element of $p$ has the same value across all the samples?  If so, it seems to me you can just add up the $x_i$ across your samples and use that total instead of doing a sample-by-sample calculation.

Comment: Can't you just add a very tiny number to each element and renormalize?